# Testing font support in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

Is there a way to preview what a given site would look like without using any system built-in fonts?

I'm currently making a website which uses Roboto Mono and Open Sans, but these fonts are installed on my local system. I'm loading these fonts from Google Fonts CDN, but it seems to not load the fonts it detects that I have locally installed.

Is there a way to preview a page without using any local fonts resident on the host system?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest renaming these fonts in your local system temporarily.